# Что такое `\U`?

Tags: c#, unicode, строковый-литерал

Встретил вот такую задачу:

```
string str1 = "\U0010FADE";
string str2 = "\U0000FADE";

Console.WriteLine(str1.Length);
Console.WriteLine(str2.Length);
```

Как оказалось, выводится 2 и 1. Что тут вообще происходит?

Я знаю только строчную `\u`, за которой должны следовать 4 шестнадцатеричных цифры.

[В MSDN для char](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char) `\U` не перечисляется, что логично - результат явно не `char`.

[Для строк](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types) - есть упоминание, но всё равно непонятно:

> The escape code `\udddd` (where `dddd` is a four-digit number) represents the Unicode character `U+dddd`. Eight-digit Unicode escape codes are also recognized: `\Udddddddd`.

[В другом месте](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Strings) говорится, что они нужны для формирования суррогатных пар, но тоже без дальнейших пояснений:

> `\Uxxxxxxxx` - Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value `xxxxxxxx` (for generating surrogates)

**Так что делает `\U` и почему во втором строке получилась не суррогатная пара, а только один символ?**

Попробовал [запустить на ideone](https://ideone.com/J33VOS), но что-то выведенные символы имеют не те коды, которые указаны в исходниках. Хотя это может быть косяком самого ideone.

Comment: Я не сишарпист и стандартов не читал, но по здравому смыслу это просто должен быть альтернативный синтаксис для указывания кода символа, который работает так же, просто длиннее. Если символ с этим кодом при кодировании в UTF-16 влезает без суррогатной пары, то один символ и будет (`\U00000041` даст самую обычную ASCII `A`), а если не влезает, то тогда уже суррогатная пара

Comment: Собственно, можно вручную прописать коды из суррогатных пар любым из этих синтаксисов и получится то же самое https://ideone.com/4Fadc8

Comment: @andreymal, т. е. для первых четырёх нулей всегда получится 1 символ, а для всего остального всегда 2?

Comment: Вроде бы да, какие-либо подвохи мне не известны

Comment: Правда, если вдуматься, становится интересно, зачем здесь восемь цифр, ведь максимальный разрешённый в юникоде символ это `\U0010FFFF` и первые два нуля будут всегда нули в любом символе. Для красоты, что ли?

Comment: @andreymal, ну, в обратную сторону не работает: https://ideone.com/TaBZ1p

Comment: Потому что нельзя просто так брать и складывать коды суррогатных пар, чтобы получить код символа из таблицы юникода

Comment: @andreymal, хм.. не обратил внимание, что они разные... Может уже напишешь ответ, как это работает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Информация в документации абсолютно правильна. Синтаксис `\Udddddddd` просто включает в строковую константу символ Юникод с кодом dddddddd. Этот символ может быть суррогатной парой и занимать две кодовые единицы UTF-16, но может быть также и обычным символом, занимающим одну кодовую единицу.

[ECMA-334](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf)

> 7.4.2 Unicode character escape sequences
>
> A Unicode escape sequence represents a Unicode code point. Unicode escape sequences are
>   processed in identifiers (§7.4.3), character literals (§7.4.5.5), and
>   regular string literals (§7.4.5.6). A Unicode escape sequence is not
>   processed in any other location (for example, to form an operator,
>   punctuator, or keyword).
>
> ```
> unicode-escape-sequence:: 
>
> \u hex-digit hex-digit hex-digit hex-digit 
> \U hex-digit hex-digit hex-digit hex-digit hex-digit hex-digit hex-digit hex-digit
> ```
>
> A Unicode character escape sequence represents the single Unicode code point 
>   formed by the
>   hexadecimal number following the “\u” or “\U” characters. Since C#
>   uses a 16-bit encoding of Unicode code points in character and string
>   values, a Unicode code point in the range U+10000 to U+10FFFF is
>   represented using two Unicode surrogate code units. Unicode code
>   points above U+FFFF are not permitted in character literals. Unicode
>   code points above U+10FFFF are invalid and are not supported.

В первом случае значение кодовой позиции больше U+10000, поэтому оно представлено двумя кодовыми единицами. Во втором случае - меньше, поэтому одной.

Другими словами, запись `\U0000FADE` эквивалентна `\uFADE`, а не `\u0000\uFADE`, как может показаться на первый взгляд (последняя действительно состоит из двух кодовых единиц).

Comment: А как `\U0010FADE` превращается в `\uDBFE\uDEDE`?

Comment: @Qwertiy это просто внутреннее байтовое представление символа U+10FADE в UTF-16. Его можно получить таким кодом: `Console.WriteLine(((ushort)str1[0]).ToString("X")+ ((ushort)str1[1]).ToString("X"));` Само число 10FADE - это представление в UTF-32.

Comment: Я имел в виду, руками между ними как-то можно переводить? Формула есть? Или ничего хорошего?

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, алгоритм описан например здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42799073/8674428